# CMake where library installation is required before add_subdirectory

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a project composed of several libraries and executables. The executables uses these libraries pointed by its final location after installation.

So, my normal procedure to build the se is:

```
cd lib1
mkdir build
make 
make install
cd ..
rm -r build

cd lib2
mkdir build
make 
make install
cd ..
rm -r build
```

And finally going to executables

```
cd exec1
mkdir build
make 
make install
cd ..
rm -r build
```

I wanna have a unique `CMakeLists.txt` where I can build my whole project chain, as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(whole)
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
add_subdirectory(exec1)
```

But `exec1` needs `lib1` and `lib2` installed, as its pointing to the definitive lib directory. When running, I´m getting:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/project/dev/lib/liblib1.so', needed by 'exec1/main'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:175: recipe for target 'exec1/CMakeFiles/aeirturesettofactory.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [exec1/CMakeFiles/exec1.dir/all] Error 2
```

How can I solve that installation dependency ?

Comment: For libraries and executables created within same project and installed using command `install(TARGETS)` CMake automatically adjusts linking for installed files. More presizely, for installed executables it assignes RPATH, which you set in [CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html) variable. See also this [wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling), described handling of RPATH in CMake.

Comment: I did not get your point. `exec1` needs to be linked to `lib1` and `lib2` during the `exec1` link phase, not after.

Comment: If you **build libraries within your project**, just link with them using target's name, not a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`external_project_add()` could be your answer. You should check it out in the cmake documentation. But I will summarize its capabilities:

- It can check out source code from a remote repo before building (but it doesn't have to).
- It can perform any necessary build steps.
- The external project can use either CMake or classic configure/make/make-install (as long as a sudo isn't required for the install step).
- It can populate CMake variables with the locations of the results.